# System.Net.Webclient not working 'WebClient' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I am trying to work with WebClient but it is giving me errors so I check in several forums (included this one) and they where telling to put

In the top of the file:

```
using System.Net
```

And after where I want use the WebClient:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.DownloadFile ("http://mysite.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\myfile.txt");
```

And I get this error:

The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In the other forums the code that I just wrote above seems to be the solution but is not working for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given your tags, it sounds like you may be building a Windows Store app - in which case you need to use [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) instead of `WebClient`.

Comment: what if my class library already using webClient and i want to use it on Windows Store App

Comment: @MikeDarwish: Then you should change it to use `HttpClient` - it's as simple as that. You just *can't* use `WebClient` in Windows Store apps, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @JonSkeet but my class already using functions on WebClient   public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient

Comment: @JonSkeet actually that is because i am using class library and i am trying to reference this library from uwp,keep in your mind i am already using this librray on my xamarin.forms.Droid project

Comment: @MikeDarwish: That doesn't magically make WebClient available in UWP though. Just because you *want* it to be feasible doesn't make it so.

Comment: @JonSkeet .. I understand you, i am trying to use same library on uwp & android projects on Xamarin.forms .thx

Comment: @MikeDarwish: And I'm saying that you'll need to either change the project to use HttpClient (assuming it's available in the version you're targeting) or use different implementatations. If you package up your library in a NuGet package, you could depend on the same *package* from both places, but with different implementations based on the target platforms.