# How to use WebClient with .NetCore?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is there any way to use a `WebClient` in a .NET Core application?
If I build the application I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I think `WebClient` is not a part of .NET Core, but is there any alternative?

Comment: I don't see `WebClient` any where in the corefx repo, `HttpClient` would probably be the alternative.

Comment: I added "Microsoft.Net.Http.Client": "1.0.0-beta3-10053" in project.json and i can instantiate a new HttpClient. And it works even with .NetCore. Maybe it is the single purpose to handle this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Net.Webclient not working 'WebClient' could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164900/system-net-webclient-not-working-webclient-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As of .Net Standard 2.0, WebClient is now available to  any implementations of the standard, including .Net Core. However, the Stack Overflow question "[Need help deciding between HttpClient and WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20530152/195653)" has some fairly good answers as to why you should be using the `HttpClient` instead.

One of the drawbacks mentioned is that there is no built-in progress reporting in the `HttpClient`. However, because it is using streams, it is possible to write your own. The answers to "[How to implement progress reporting for Portable HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21644313/195653)" provides an example for reporting the progress of the response stream.

If you're targeting prior versions of the standard, you'll need to use `HttpClient` as `WebClient` is not available prior to .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: It should be built on top of System.Net.Http in 1.2.0 version https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11794

Answer (score 4):

`WebClient` is now available in .Net Standard 2.0 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netstandard-2.0