# Download image from url to the server to process in asp.net 5 api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have to download an image from a URL to the server with an API controller.
I can't use the WebClient.DownloadFile at ASP.NET 5. Is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided any details why WebClient doesn't work for you, but alternatively you could use the newer [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) class:

```
public static async Task DownloadAsync(Uri requestUri, string filename)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri))
    using (
        Stream contentStream = await (await client.SendAsync(request)).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
        stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 3145728, true))
    {
        await contentStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, not save the file and got an exception.

Comment: What exception did you get? I tested the code and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: It does work, I made a mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I think `WebClient` wasn't added until ASP.Net Core v1.2.0 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227219/how-to-use-webclient-with-netcore

Answer (score 4):

I think this version is a little bit simpler:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
using (var contentStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(i.SourceUri))
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileUploadPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 1048576, true))
{
    await contentStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream); 
}
```