# Dotnet in Fedora 25: WebClient does not exist in System.Net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, fedora-25

I am using Dotnet on Fedora 25. I used [these instructions](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/nmilosev/dotnet-sig/) to install Dotnet with RPMs for my distribution, as there are no official packages for Fedora 25:

Things look fine:

```
$ dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-1-003175
```

I am trying to run a simple WebClient example, created with Visual Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.WebClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var webClient = new WebClient()) 
            {
                var url = [someurl];
                var htmlCode = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(htmlCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I added the `using` statements one-by-one, running into this issue:

```
$ dotnet build
Project cbsearchui_test (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
Compiling test_project for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1
/usr/lib64/dotnetcore/dotnet compile-csc 
@test_project/obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/dotnet-
compile.rsp returned Exit Code 1
test_project/Program.cs(4,18): error CS0234: 
The type or namespace name 'WebClient' does not exist in the namespace 
'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Compilation failed.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:00.6661503
```

This is my `project.json`, automatically generated by VS Code:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

I am struggling to understand if this is related to my specific Dotnet installation and/or to Fedora 25. Similar questions seem to refer to [compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seems-ok?noredirect=1&lq=1), [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found?rq=1), [bad usage statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164900/system-net-webclient-not-working-webclient-could-not-be-found) etc. But none of them seem applicable to this issue.

I also tried changing the dependency to `netcoreapp` to version 1.0.0 instead of 1.1.0, but the same error persists.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, WebClient doesn't exist in dotnet core until version 2.0.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-2.0

Comment: Just don't use WebClient, it's obsolete. It's been replaced by HttpClient even in .NET Framework projects on Windows

Comment: This comment seems to conflict with the earlier ones. @J.Steen's comment indicates that I need a more recent .NET core version to use `WebClient` wheras @panagiotis says that `WebClient` is obsolete. Should the solution hence be to upgrade .NET core (once it is available for (Fedora) Linux) or to replace `WebClient` with `HttpClient`?

Comment: You could simply use HttpClient instead. It's more "advanced", but is already implemented and will likely not go away anytime soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a conclusion from the comments, the answer is: `WebClient` cannot be used in (Fedora) Linux because .NET 2.0 is not available.
Solution is to use `HttpClient` instead.